# Automate the process when a new file is uploaded in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-transcribe

Is there a way to setup a trigger so that when a new file is uploaded in "Bucket A", AWS will transcribe the audio immediately?

Currently, I will have to manually transcribe which is not ideal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is any native support for this today, but you could set this up pretty easily using S3 Bucket Notifications to trigger a Lambda function that then calls AWS transcribe.

```
S3 Bucket -> Uploaded Object -> S3 Bucket Notification -> Lambda -> AWS Transcribe
```

Setting up Bucket notifications to Lambda: [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3 - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html)

And then you'd simply call the AWS Transcribe API (JS SDK): [Class: AWS.TranscribeService — AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/TranscribeService.html#startTranscriptionJob-property)

Comment: This is super helpful! I'm not really familiar with AWS. So what I've done is create a new function using lambda from an existing template. Do I erase the code and replace it with your 2nd link? Its written in node.js i beleive

Comment: Yup though it can be written in any of the supported Lambda runtimes if you're not familiar/comfortable with javascript.

Comment: In practice this is not a scaleable solution. S3 events contrary to general belief is not reliably generated for every file on S3. Under heavy parallel uploads events are throttled. If your encoder or file processor relies solely on event to process the file you may end up with unprocessed uploaded files.